# Dialog and button callback in Haskell OpenGL

Tags: haskell, opengl, glut

[Graphics.UI.GLUT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.7.0.13/docs/Graphics-UI-GLUT-Callbacks-Window.html#g:14) has a *Dial and Button callback*. I don't find any example of use of this callback. I wanted to have one because currently I use the keyboard and the mouse callbacks and this is not enough and not user-friendly.

I've tried to do one such callback. In my program:

```
dial :: IORef GLdouble -> DialAndButtonBoxCallback
dial zoom index =
  case index of
    DialAndButtonBoxDial 1 1 -> zoom $~! (+1)
    _                        -> return ()
```

Then I expect to see a button (button `1`) in the OpenGL window which would increment `zoom` when I press on this button (`zoom $~! (+1)` zooms the graphic, I use it in the keyboard callback currently, no problem with that).

Then in my `main` file:

```
  zoom <- newIORef 0.0
  dialAndButtonBoxCallback $= Just (dial zoom)
```

The code compiles. But when I run the program, there's no dialog box appearing anywhere.

I would appreciate any help. Maybe I have to create a dialog box first ? I don't see anything like this in the documentation.

Comment: I'm afraid OpenGL is not a GUI and this is not possible. So what is the purpose of this callback ? Otherwise is there something to create buttons and use the mouse callback with the help of the position of the cursor ?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dial and button box is not a dialog box. It’s a special purpose type of hardware, like a mouse, keyboard, joystick, or steering wheel. Eg [this company makes some](http://simracinghardware.com/).

Glut is not a gui library like gtk. It lets you get user input and draw things on the screen. You need to figure out exactly how to draw all your user interface components if you want to use glut

Comment: Ok, thank you. Finally I've found another solution: I use `attachMenu` to create some menus. That works fine.

Comment: So I guess the `"Tablet button" is also some type of hardware ?

Comment: GLUT is mainly about talking to hardware. Either peripherals, speakers (?) or graphics cards.

Comment: @DanRobertson: Actually GLUT is a extremly simplistic framework to create bare bones OpenGL applications. It creates windows and OpenGL contexts for you, does have very limited support for showing popup menus and allows you to register callbacks for a very narrow set of events. It was never meant for developing "serious" applications, but rather provide a scaffolding for quick and dirty OpenGL demo hacks, or if you want to show off specific functions of a library that interfaces with OpenGL. *Don't use it in anything serious!*

Comment: Ok, so I wasted my time with these callbacks. Fortunately, `attachMenu` is my savior :-)

Comment: @datenwolf I find you're a bit hard with OpenGL/GLUT (I don't mean you're wrong). They allow nice 3D animations even so. I'm also using the R package `rgl` for 3D anims,  it has some advantages but it renders the scenes very slowly as compared to Haskell. Of course this is not for GUI development.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I *love* OpenGL, and there's nothing wrong with it. It's GLUT which I love to diss, because it's such a widely misused library. And for some reason (I guess it's the examples in the OpenGL Red Book) **a lot** of people are under the impression that for some reason GLUT was kind of a vital part of OpenGL itself or the OpenGL ecosystem and that you always had to use it. I've seen oh so many programs using Qt, GTK, plain Win32 or similar that threw a `glutInit`/`glutInitDisplayMode` somewhere at the beginning of the main function and then never use it again.